# Retain Header/Column Name when converting Excel file to SQL file

Tags: sql, excel

How do I make the first row of my table in the Excel format become the Column Name of my table when I convert it to SQL file? My database currently has 60 columns and when I convert it to SQL format, I have to retype the column names manually because the default displays COL1, COL2, COL3 ... Or is it impossible?

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you're doing here.  What exactly do you mean by "SQL file" ?

Comment: SQL file. A file that has a .sql file extension. The file format of a database in MySQL.

Comment: "when I convert it to SQL file" - how are you doing this ?

Comment: I save the excel file as a .csv file then import this .csv file to phpmyadmin.

Comment: Sounds like a MySQL import question and not an Excel to CSV question.